# Kubernetes: Ingress to communicate with internal services using HTTPS

Tags: kubernetes

I have a service (Node REST app, let's call it ABC) within the cluster. This app listens to two ports, one runs on HTTP and the other on HTTPS.

I use Ingress. I can see Ingress only use HTTP port to communicate with ABC. I got confirmed this by stopping the HTTP and running ABC on HTTPS only.

Do I have to make any specific setup in Ingress so to use HTTPS instead of HTTP to communicate with ABC? Or is it a pattern to run services within a cluster on HTTP when use Ingress?

Ingress yaml :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: abc.containers.myhost.net
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-test-node
          servicePort: 9080
        path: my-test-node/xyz
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - abc.containers.myhost.net
    secretName: abc1
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing your ingress resource yaml file?

Comment: I think you need to rephrase the question.
service != app.
apps don't listen to HTTP or/and HTTPS ports, they just listen to some ports. If these requests need to be secured, that's another question.

Comment: Why would you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: Are you using nginx ingress controller? Did you take a look at the docs? https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/annotations.md
you might want this annotation if you want the ssl pass through the ingress to the pod
 nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthroug
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
spec: rules: http -> https

Comment: Check that your cert in your secret matches the host. Otherwise the ingress controller will just ignore and serve the default backend when you go to https